# Build histogram from objects of type counter

Tags: python, histogram, counter

I used Counter from collections to generate a large list of Counters, i.e List = [Counter({'A': 4}), Counter({'A': 2}), Counter({'A': 4}, {'B', 3})...].

I would like to build histogram from that list, where each bin of that histogram would be one specific type of counter, i.e having the same number of each element counted by the counter.

Here is an example

```
from collections import Counter
data = [['A', 'B', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'B'], ['C']]
data_counters = []
for d in data:
    data_counters.append(Counter(d))
```

I could generate a list of all possible counter outcomes and then count how many times each counter occurs in data_counters. But this is difficult since the number of all possible outcomes is large.

Strictly speaking this problem is just a calculation of a multi-dimensional histogram, where each dimension corresponds to a letter. But the point is that I want to avoid that and only use the bins of the combinations of letters that occur many times, without looking at detailed information.

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: I think I did not explain the problem very clearly. I started from some data of the form data = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'A', 'B'], ['B', 'A'], [], []...]. From every element in data I extracted a Counter, which gives me a list of Counters. I want to build a histogram of counters, not a histogram of the elements counted by the counters. The bins would indicate Counter(A1 B1 C1), Counter(A2, B1)..

Comment: If you have additional information, please edit the question. You should also provide a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added an example

Comment: You aren't asking a question. See [ask] and as @Mr.T suggested, create a [mcve] describing how and why you aren't able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter objects are not hashable, so we cannot use the same counter function on them again. One way to deal with this situation is to use [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=frozenset#frozenset) instead of Counter dictionaries. The disadvantage is that we have to re-translate the frozensets into something like strings that matplotlib can use for the bar chart, aka the histogram:

```
from collections import Counter
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data_list = [['A', 'B', 'B'], ['B', 'A', 'B'], ['A', 'A', 'B'], ['C']]
data_counter = Counter(frozenset(Counter(d).items()) for d in data_list)

plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha="right")
plt.bar([str(list(x)) for x in data_counter.keys()], data_counter.values())
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]